# How to invisibly output part of the output in R

Tags: r, function

In my `R` function below, I want object `output` to be always **visibly** outputted. But I was wondering if there is a way to also **invisibly but extractably** output object `cl`, which is the function call, with that?

If not possible, how to visibly add the `cl` to the `output` so that `cl` is extractable after function execution along with `output`?

```
foo <- function(one = T){

 cl <- match.call()  

output <- if(one) data.frame(d = 6:8, long = c(F, F,F)) else
list(Study1 = data.frame(d = 6:8, long = c(F, F,F)), Study2 = data.frame(d = 9:11, long = c(T, T, F)) )

 return(output)
 }

# Example of use:
foo()
```

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, function call (i.e., `cl`) along with `output`.

Comment: would adding `return(list(output, cl))` give what you want? What do you mean by "extractable" ?

Comment: @RonakShah, I mean if you run `a <- foo()` then you can `a$cl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `return` `list` of output from the function

```
foo <- function(one = T){
     cl <- match.call()  
     output <- if(one) data.frame(d = 6:8, long = c(F, F,F)) else
     list(Study1 = data.frame(d = 6:8, long = c(F, F,F)), 
         Study2 = data.frame(d = 9:11, long = c(T, T, F)) )
    return(list(output = output, cl = cl))
}
```

and then use `eval` to evaluate the function

```
a = foo(TRUE)

eval(a$cl)
#$output
#  d  long
#1 6 FALSE
#2 7 FALSE
#3 8 FALSE

#$cl
#foo(one = TRUE)
```